# How to create custom exception handler class in Struts2

Tags: exception, struts2

How to create custom exception handler class in Struts2? I have tried adding the exception code in `execute()` but failed.

Comment: *custom exception handler* - What do you mean by that?

Comment: I want to create user defined exception class (like IdIncorrectException class).

Comment: And what is not working?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I hope that this guidelines will be usefull for your question, since it looks a little too broad, so if you have a specific requirement just edit your question. First of all I suggest you to read the official documentation in order to retrieve information about the [Exception handling](https://struts.apache.org/docs/exception-handling.html), [Exception configuration](https://struts.apache.org/docs/exception-configuration.html) and [Exception Interceptor](https://struts.apache.org/docs/exception-interceptor.html).

Now, I try to be more detailed as I can two explain how you can handle the exceptions in Struts2:

- Global exception handling: everytime your application throws an exception, Struts2 will handle the result with the `<global-results>` and `<global-exception-mappings>` tags in `struts.xml` file.
- Action exception handling: everytime your specific action throws an exception, Struts2 will handle the result `<exception-mapping>` tag inside a `<action>` tag

**Global exception handling**

> Using the Struts 2 framework you can specify in the struts.xml how the framework should handle uncaught exceptions. The handling logic can apply to all actions (global exception handling) or to a specific action. Let's first discuss how to enable global exception handling.
>
> To enable global exception handling you need to add two nodes to struts.xml: global-exception-mapping and global-results. For example examine struts.xml from the exception_handling project.
>
> ```xml
> <global-results>
>       <result name="securityerror">/securityerror.jsp</result>
>       <result name="error">/error.jsp</result>
> </global-results>
>
> <global-exception-mappings>
>      <exception-mapping exception="org.apache.struts.register.exceptions.SecurityBreachException" result="securityerror" />
>      <exception-mapping exception="java.lang.Exception" result="error" />
> </global-exception-mappings>
> ```

Now when a `SecurityBreachException` is thrown, the `securityerror.jsp` will be loaded. In my opinion global exception are very usefull for generic errors. For example you can create an ApplicationException view with a form used to send to your assistance the stack trace of the problem.

**Action exception handling**

> If you need to handle an exception in a specific way for a certain action you can use the exception-mapping node within the action node.
>
> ```xml
> <action name="actionspecificexception" class="org.apache.struts.register.action.Register" method="throwSecurityException">
>       <exception-mapping exception="org.apache.struts.register.exceptions.SecurityBreachException" result="login" />
>       <result>/register.jsp</result>
>       <result name="login">/login.jsp</result>
> </action>
> ```

In this example when `throwSecurityException` method of the `Register` action throws a `SecurityBreachException` it returns a `LOGIN` result and the `login.jsp` is loaded. I've used this kind of solution for actions that may throw errors after a validation (for example to execute CRUD operations in my database).

**Custom error jsp**

> By default, the ExceptionMappingInterceptor adds the following values to the Value Stack:
>
> - exception : The exception object itself
> - exceptionStack : The value from the stack trace

You can use them to create a custom jsp that prints the error occurred and the stacktrace. Here you have an example:

```xml
<h2>An unexpected error has occurred</h2>
<p>
    Please report this error to your system administrator
    or appropriate technical support personnel.
    Thank you for your cooperation.
</p>
<hr/>
<h3>Error Message</h3>
<s:actionerror/>
<p>
    <s:property value="%{exception.message}"/>
</p>
<hr/>
<h3>Technical Details</h3>
<p>
    <s:property value="%{exceptionStack}"/>
</p>
```

**Logs**

I think that also the [LoggingExceptions](https://struts.apache.org/docs/exception-handling.html#ExceptionHandling-LoggingExceptions) paragraph will be usefull.